# He stayed while she talked / was talking to her?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, conjunctions

> He stayed while she talked to her.
>
> He waited while she was talking to her.

Are both correct? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and no difference as far as I'm concerned. The initial verb "stayed" and "waited" almost renders the next verb talked and talking insignificant, both events took place in the past and, for me, the verb talked and talking are pretty much conveying the same meaning whichever way you've used them.